# Mysql gem error when installing free fat crm

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am getting the following error when trying to run `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production` command.

I am trying to install free fat crm

```
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'my
    sql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by Act
    iveRecord).
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/acti
    ve_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
    ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in
    `<top (required)>'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database
    "=>"fat_free_crm_production", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "h
    ost"=>"127.0.0.1", "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}
    rake aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not load
    ed. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum
     required by ActiveRecord).

    Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.

    Tasks: TOP => db:create
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Is there `mysql2` gem in your `Gemfile`? Add that and run `bundle install`

Comment: Where  do I find the gemfile?

Comment: https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/blob/master/Gemfile